# Typescript does not type check objects when created with new?

Tags: typescript

Why is type checking not working with someCat2??

```
interface A{
    x: number;
}

function test(something: A){}

let someCat = {cat : "miao"}

function MakeCat(){
    this.cat = "miao";
}

let someCat2 = new MakeCat();

test(someCat2); //  --->> typescript DOES NOT marks the error <<-------
test(someCat); //typescript marks the error
```

I'm writing some details for being able to submit this question :)

Comment: If I paste that into the TypeScript playground, there are lots of errors reported. 

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=44#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQyfIB4BcyIArgLYBG0A3JgL6aYwkgJjAD2IykAzmAApeHMhDAALUAHMiqAJToGmADZjkw0QGE4YZAF5k6BDuREARGWBwOZpc1bsuyALJwA1hG2CF2XBOC8AHTGugYWVja0Sqq6Gp46AEz6xBAA7i7u8d60mHyCcV4JctTIAPSlOAC01QB8NTwAngAOELwIUMBNugAiAPIAogDKyAByvQAqyGRwUG68POIo0FAcUMgAPOvV29W5rfkiWcVlpWDNre2dutOz8xJLUCtQQA

Comment: Basically the `let someCat2 = new MakeCat();` is already flagged as an error, so TypeScript then assumes that `someCat2` is of type `any` and proceeds with reporting any other errors.

Comment: Why is it wrong? all the life i declared objects this way ahahah

Comment: That's the way you declare a "class" (sort of) in old JavaScript, but TypeScript has full support for classes.  Try this: I declared the class properly and changed the interface.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQyfIXMALmQGcwpQBzAbkwF9NMYBXEBMYAexGUjIAoSnALYQwACyrFUASnQNMAGzGkREAMIFkAXmTp8YZMQBEw4HE7GFCRXBIlkAWTgBrDVqy483MlGbtOKH4AB2YAI0VgBDwtXVNzSxk9Ri8GBWVDIVFNMAAmHWQQCAB3J1d3MH4ZWkw+SqyK3OrkAHoWnABaLoA+bt4AT2CIEgQKYMMAEQB5AFEAZWQAOSmAFWRhOCgXBwkUaChA5AAeI66zrtrh+rUc5rawQeHR4HH1ze3ecT2oA6g4IA

Comment: Is there a solution that dose not require the use of the class keyword?

Comment: Well yeah, use JavaScript :-) .Why do you want to use TypeScript if you're not using TypeScript features?

Comment: BTW modern JavaScript also supports classes.  Using functions isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: I like Typescript but i hate javascript classes... i sees them as useless overkill that hide the true paradigm... so I avoid them :/

Comment: You're fighting the language that you're using, which is never a productive thing.  I'd suggest you get used to classes if you want to use TypeScript.  My answer below shows how.

Answer (score 0):

`someCat2` here has the type `any`, and `any` type is [a special type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) in TypeScript that

> you can access any properties of it (which will in turn be of type any), call it like a function, assign it to (or from) a value of any type, or pretty much anything else that’s syntactically legal

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected syntax.  I also changed the interface so that there are no errors.

```
interface A{
    cat: string;
}

function test(something: A){}

let someCat = {cat : "miao"}

class MakeCat {
    constructor(public cat = "miao") {

    }
}

let someCat2 = new MakeCat();

test(someCat2);
test(someCat);
```

The error in your syntax was being reported, but then TypeScript assumes that `someCat2` is of type `any` and proceeds reporting other errors.

You can try it out at the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIG8BQyfIXMALmQGcwpQBzAbkwF9NMYBXEBMYAexGUjIAoSnALYQwACyrFUASnQNMAGzGkREAMIFkAXmTp8YZMQBEw4HE7GFCRXBIlkAWTgBrDVqy483MlGbtOKH4AB2YAI0VgBDwtXVNzSxk9Ri8GBWVDIVFNMAAmHWQQCAB3J1d3MH4ZWkw%20SqyK3OraiAEGnOqgA).